# How to view content of commit-id shown by git rebase?

Tags: git, version-control

The "git rebase" command shows a list of some commit ids to pick operations for them; the problem is that all history messages are the same (empty) and I don't know how they are correlated to SHA1 IDs shown in git gui. Is there any way to view commit's content by this id shown by git rebase?

Comment: As for deleting [this answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129372/how-to-replace-all-empty-history-messages-on-windows) -- please note that it's not too nice to delete questions that people have spent time answering?

Comment: The same question already was answered on SO before, and the answer to deleted question was not good anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`git show`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html)
should do it

Example

```
git show 8e222c8
```

More info

```
For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. It also presents
the merge commit in a special format as produced by git diff-tree --cc.
```